# Laravel redirect not working at all in the entire project

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Am trying to return redirect back after saving a record to DB but it fails. Generally only the login redirect and home are working. Return view is also working fine.

This is what I have tried:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success',"Product updated successfully");

return redirect('main/products');

return Redirect::to('main/products');
```

However, if I inspect on the browser under response, I can see that the HTML code of the view is return, just not displayed.
[image: This is the response I get on inspect...no errors]

Yes, I know, seems simple but it's frustrating me. Since it's affecting my entire system am guessing there is something am missing its not the syntax.

My Full method is:

```
public function updateProducts(){
       request()->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required'
        ]);
        $product=Product::findOrFail(\request('id'));
        $product->name=\request('name');
        $product->description=\request('description');
        $product->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with('success',"Product updated successfully");  
    }
```

my blade:

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')

@section('page_heading','Products ')

@section('section')
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <hr class="sidebar-divider">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                        <a href="{{url('/main/system')}}" class="btn btn-success btn-icon-split">
                            <span class="icon text-white-50">
                                <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="text">Back</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4    "><h4 class="card-title">African Guarantee Fund Products</h4></div>
                <div class="col-lg-5">

                    <a href="#add_product" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-icon-split">
                        <span class="icon text-white-50">
                            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                        </span> <span class="text">New Guarantee Product</span>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="card border-left-success shadow h-100 py-2">
    <div class="card-body">
        @include('common.bootstrap_table_ajax',[
        'table_headers'=>["name","description","action"],
        'data_url'=>'/main/system/products/list',
        'base_tbl'=>'products'
        ])
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr class="sidebar-divider">
  <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="favoritesModalLabel" id="add_product">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"
                id="add_product">New Guarantee Product</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-icon-split" class="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
                    {!! Form::autoForm(['product_name','description'],"main/system/products/add") !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="favoritesModalLabel" id="product_modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"
                id="product_modal">New Guarantee Product</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-icon-split" class="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                 {!!Form::autoForm(\App\Models\Main\Product::class,"main/system/products/update")!!}

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    @endsection
```

Comment: How are you calling these urls? Are you using ajax? What is the error you are getting? `it doesn't work` doesn't really say much.

Comment: Well, the products am saving to the database get saved fine. There is no error return see image below. Am not using ajax, just the normal laravel redirect

Comment: instead of rediract retur a route and rediract with jquery

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Are you calling the route which updates the database via ajax? If so, you cannot return a redirect. Also please give some details about your environment (webserver, i.e. apache or nginx) and have a look at the response headers (should contain a `Location` header in case of a redirect).

Comment: See above I have added the full method am calling. Am on localhost xampp, apache. Am calling url to save from html form post

Comment: Are you using web middleware in your route? You shouldn't.

Comment: yes am using web middleware, lemme remove and see

Comment: I removed the web middleware but still same problem

Comment: Show your blade template, too

Comment: sometime php artisan cache:clear would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following code to check

```
return redirect()->to('main/products');

             OR

return redirect()->route('main_products'); // where main_products is the route name mentioned in the web.php
```

Comment: tried this..doesn't work also. Also tried clearing all caches but still didn't work

Comment: make use of the code return redirect()->back(); to check

Answer (score 0):

You can use this option,

```
public function updateProducts(){
        request()->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required'
        ]);
        $product=Product::findOrFail(\request('id'));
        $product->name=\request('name');
        $product->description=\request('description');
        $product->save();
        Session::flash('success',"Product updated successfully");
        return redirect()->back();  
    }
```

and use variable in Blade file as

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
    <p>{{ Session::get('success') }}</p>
@endif
```

and don't forget to use this

```
use Session;
```

Answer (score 0):

Good news: I fixed the problem. Bad news: It was a silly mistake.

I had put an HTML line of code at the end of my resources blade to test if all resources were being loaded by console logging the value. This is the line I had added:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="material_page_loaded" value="1">
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry guys I took your time for this. I appreciate your help.